# PHP: Empezar el update con valor 1 y no 0

Tags: php, sql

Tengo una tabla en la que hago drag and drop, arrastro una fila y la coloco en otra posición.

El campo 'orden' empieza por 1 y cuando hago un drag and drop se actualizan a partir de 0. Me gustaría que se mantenga la actualización a partir del campo orden con valor 1 y no 0.

Imagen de antes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen del despues:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La función que hace el update es esta:

```
public function updateOrder(Request $request)
   {

       $queryParams = [];

       $ids = $request->ids;
       //el query será definido en su totalidad de forma manual
       $query = 'UPDATE projects SET `order` = CASE id ';
       //agregamos cada parámetro de orden y de id al array para respetar las convenciones de PDO
       foreach ($ids as $order => $id) {
           $query .= 'WHEN ? THEN ? ';
           $queryParams[] = (int) $id;
           $queryParams[] = (int) $order;
       }

       //por último agregamos los ids implicados en el update
       $queryParams = array_merge($queryParams, $ids);

       //generamos los ? necesarios para el array de ids en el query PDO
       $whereInArray = array_fill(0, count($ids), '?');
       $whereInString = implode(", ", $whereInArray);

       //agregamos dicho string generado al query final
       $query .= "END WHERE id IN ($whereInString)";

       //realizamos el update
       DB::update($query, $queryParams);
   }
```

¿Que debería de cambiar en la function update?

Comment: De Laravel tiene mas bien poco tu código, no usas Eloquent ni Modelos para nada, por lo que es PHP puro.

Comment: @ManuelRobles tal vez me falta experiencia, pero la función yo veo claramente que es de un Controller, en este caso un controller de Laravel, y no recuerdo en PHP puro haber utilizado DB::update.

Comment: @Lluís Puig Ferrer el "DB" es una clase genérica de cualquier  POO. En Laravel se usa el gestor "Eloquent" para gestionar todas las operaciones y salvo ciertos puntos que se usa el "DB:raw()" (en casos que necesites un alto performance o casos no contemplados en eloquent)

Comment: Es decir, es una función de PHP puro, crees que con Eloquent seria mas sencillo? @ManuelRobles

Comment: Si tienes que empezar de 0 a comprender como funciona no, pero si ya sabes manejar eloquent bien, si.

Comment: Más o menos se como funciona, seria genial si podemos hacer un chat y voy haciendo y te voy comentando. Ya que estoy usando un MVC creo que seria una buena practica utilizar los métodos de este.

Comment: Este caso es una excepción en la cual Eloquent no puede hacer lo que necesitas, no te dejes confundir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solucionado**

`$queryParams[] = (int) $order+1;`

Comment: Por favor, acepta esta respuesta para dar la pregunta como cerrada.

Comment: No puedo aceptar una respuesta mía hasta pasado dos días @Muriano